# How do I receive payments on the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: python, google-chrome, paypal, store, payment

I have an app (The Ultimate Weather App) on the Chrome Web Store.  The developer dashboard says that I have 10 weekly users.
[image: a busy cat]

Although the app costs $9.99, Google Merchant says that there have been no transactions.

[image: a busy cat]
I have monthly payments. Should I wait until the end of the month or do I have to do that licensing API thing?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Google Wallet for monthly subscription for your app? If yes, it automatically charges user monthly or yearly according to your subscription plan. Here is the help [article](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/1053340?hl=en). Also, you have to use the licensing API to check if the user had paid the subscription fee or not. Here is the help [article](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#cws-licensing-api).